# Formik value can't be accessed somehow

Tags: reactjs, formik

My Formik form gets its initial values from a blank object generator, however if the user have already added data to it, the function returns the same object, just with the data inside.

But I'm having massive issues to just display that data in the form.

So, to test it, every time a field gets generated, I run this:

```
console.log(formik);
console.log('Ticket' + formNumber + '.Field' + data.ticketDetailForm[i].id)
console.log(formik.values['Ticket' + formNumber + '.Field' + data.ticketDetailForm[i].id])
```

So in order I log:

- The object
- The key where the value sits
- The value

Which I would expect to output:

- {Ticket1: {Field1: "ANSWER" ...
- Ticket1.Field1
- ANSWER

Instead I'm getting:

[image]

So how can I get back the object with all the key value pairs in the correct places in the actual object, but when I try to log just the value, it messes up...

But then, when I actually type into a field and let Formik update the value, then it logs. So there can't be any errors in the "key" field (which I use in the value prop of the `<input>`) since my console.log is the same as the "value" field, which works when Formik updates it.

**EDIT** - MORE INFO

I need to create a dynamic form based on information in an object provided by the client, so I'm generating various "Tickets" and then simply creating "Field1, Field2 and Field3" in each Ticket, which I will then assign a 'name' on the backend.

So the function at the bottom generates an object to be used as "initialValues" based on the amount of Tickets and Fields needed.

Here's my code:

```
export default function TicketDetails({formData, editFormData}) {
  
  const initialObject = generateInitialValues(formData);

  const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: initialObject,
    onSubmit: values => {
      editFormData({ticketDetails: values});
    },
  });

  return (
    <form id="ticketDetails" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <GenerateCards formik={formik} />
      <div className='h-6'></div>
    </form>
  );
}

function GenerateCards({formik}){
  let output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nrOfTickets; i++){
    output.push(
    <div key={i} className="divide-y divide-gray-200 overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white shadow mt-6">
      <div className="px-4 py-5 sm:px-6">
        <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Ticket #{i+1}</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="px-4 py-5 sm:p-6 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-2 lg:gap-4">
        <GenerateFields formNumber={i+1} formik={formik}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  };
  return output;
}

function GenerateFields({formNumber, formik}) { // Generate form internals from firebase object

  let fields = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.ticketDetailForm.length; i++){

    console.log(formik.values);
    console.log(['Ticket' + formNumber + '.Field' + data.ticketDetailForm[i].id]);
    console.log(formik.values['Ticket' + formNumber + '.Field' + data.ticketDetailForm[i].id])

    fields.push(
      <div key={i}>
      <label className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 pl-0.5 pb-1">{data.ticketDetailForm[i].label}</label>
      <input
        name={"Ticket" + formNumber + ".Field" + data.ticketDetailForm[i].id}
        value={formik.values['Ticket' + formNumber + '.Field' + data.ticketDetailForm[i].id]}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        type={data.ticketDetailForm[i].type}
        className="mb-4 block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
        placeholder={data.ticketDetailForm[i].placeholder}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return fields;
}

function generateInitialValues(formData) {
  if(!formData.ticketDetails){
    let object = {};    
    for (let i = 0; i < nrOfTickets; i++){
      object["Ticket" + (i+1)] = {};
      for (let j = 0; j < data.ticketDetailForm.length; j++){
        object["Ticket" + (i+1)]["Field" + (j+1)]="";
      }
    }
    return(object);
  } else {
    return formData.ticketDetails;
  }
}
```

I don't *think* that the issue is in the generation of this object, since filling out the form and submitting fills in the data in the correct places. But formik just can't READ that data later.

Comment: can you provide code sandbox link or code to look at

Comment: @kuuhak-u I added the code in an edit